# Enabeling PHP LDAP with Lighttpd

Tags: php, ldap, lighttpd, arch-linux

I'm experiencing some difficulties enabling LDAP in an Archlinux environment with Lighttpd (lighty) and PHP. I have downloaded and installed the php-ldap module, enabled it in php.ini and the phpinfo() shows this under "Configure command"

```
'--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl'
```

Which for me indicates that it is enabled. But when I use a LDAP command, such as `ldap_connect()`, it throws an "undefined function" error back. I did kill the Lighttpd process and start it again before testing.

I have also installed the required packages `libldap` and `libsasl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the version of the LDAP module was incompatible with the PHP version. PHP 5.3 and the LDAP module 5.4.

Tested in test environment with 5.4 on both the LDAP module and PHP and it works.